# How to write a function to check the array for symmetry using lambda calculus?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

I am studying Lambda Calculus. I need to define a lambda image of a syndicate that returns true or false depending on whether the input array is symmetric from the center or not.
I will be very happy for any of your help, since this topic is very difficult for me.
I understand how to define basic constructors such as true or false, as well as addition and multiplication.
I have some algorithm, as I would like to do:

1. Find the number of elements in the stack.
2. Pull half (with rounding down) of the stack onto another stack.
3. If the number of elements was odd, remove the element from the first stack.
4. In pairs, remove elements from the stacks and compare, if not equal, return the constructor false, if the stacks are empty, return the constructor true.

UPDATE

1.lenght = λl.l (λx.succ), where succ = λnfx.n f (f x)

Comment: How do you represent arrays, don't you rather mean lists? Also what does it contain, Church numerals?

Comment: @ThéoWinterhalter, 
by array I mean an ordered set of values.
Nothing is said to me about the contents of this set.

Comment: @ThéoWinterhalter, 
most likely it is a spiok that contains natural numbers

Comment: Your approach would probably work, but you need to know how arrays (or stacks now?) are represented, or is it also your job to find a representation of those?

Comment: @ThéoWinterhalter, An ordered set of values ​​(for example, <1,2,3,3,2,1>) is fed to the input. My function should return TRUE if this set is symmetric. That is, X(i) = X(n+1-i).
I myself am free to determine what to call this set of values. Since in the lambda calculus we cannot gain access to an element by index, it is best to represent this set of values ​​as a stack or queue.

Comment: Right, so you have a Church-encoding of a list, which basically gives you a fold on it, then you just have to do what you said. What is the thing blocking you?

Comment: @ThéoWinterhalter, 
I do not understand the syntax.
Simple examples are given to me more or less, but such an algorithm I do not understand how to paint.

Comment: @ThéoWinterhalter, 
I added an update and wrote a function to calculate the length of the list. But I do not understand how it works (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pure λ-calculus, you do not have access to any data-type, but you can still represent them with so-called Church-encodings.

For instance, the natural numbers in unary representation can either be `0` (`z`) or the successor (`s`) of another natural number `n`, i.e, representing `n+1`.
So you have `z`, `s z`, `s (s z)`, `s (s (s z))`, etc.
To represent them in λ-calculus, you use functions taking `z` and `s` as arguments:
`λz.λs.z`, `λz.λs.s z`, `λz.λs.s (s z)`, `λz.λs.s (s (s z))`, etc.

What's pretty cool about this representation is that it also gives you a recursor on natural numbers, i.e, a way to build stuff inductively on your natural number.

Say you want to test if `n` is `0`, just write `n true (λm. false)` (where `true` and `false` would represent booleans, but they could be anything really). You then have

```
0 true (λm. false) = true
1 true (λm. false) = (λm. false) true = false
2 true (λm. false) = (λm. false) ((λm. false) true) = false
...
```

meaning you can distinguish `0` from the rest of the Church numerals.
Basically when you feed a Church numeral `b` and `f` you give the image of `0` as `b` and a function `f` to go from the image of `n` to the image of `n+1`.

To write the `succ` function to add one to a natural number, you want to add one `s` in front of its representation:

```
succ n = λz.λs.s (n z s)
```

The `n z s` is synonymous to the removal of the two leading `λ`s.

Now lists can be represented the same way. A list can either be the empty list (`[]` or `nil`) or some element (`head`) attached to some other list (`tail`): `head :: tail` or `cons head tail`.
We do the same *trick*:
`nil` is `λn.λc.n` and `cons x nil` is `λn.λc.c x n`, `cons y (cons x nil)` is `λn.λc.c y (c x n)`, etc.

Similarly you can feed a base case and a function to a list to perform a *fold*.

```
cons x (cons y nil) b f = f x (f y b)
(cons x1 (cons x2 (... (cons xn nil) ...))) b f = f x1 (f x2 (... (f xn b) ...)))
```

To get the length you have to note that the length of `nil` is `0` and that the length of `cons x l` is `succ (length l)`, without depending on the `x`.
So `length l = l 0 (λ_.λn. succ n)`.

You should go on and build primitives like this to eventually solve your problem.

---

Next you want to write `firstn` the function which takes an integer `n` and a list `l` and returns the `n` first elements.
Basically you have

```
firstn 0 l = nil
firstn (n+1) nil = nil
firstn (n+1) (cons a l) = cons a (firstn n l)
```

so you first do an analysis on the natural number, and then on the list.
I will write it as a function taking a natural number and returning a function taking a list and returning a list.

```
firstn = λn. n (λl. nil) (λr.λl. l nil (λa.λl. cons a (r l)))
```

In there `r` represents the recursive call `firstn n` when I'm defining `firstn (n+1)`.

It can feel a bit tricky, and to be honest knowing how to write this in a proper functional language with pattern-matching helps. I personally tested these in coq.

---

Perhaps even easier to understand would first to write a case analysis function on lists, but for that we need to build pairs.

A pair is something composed of two elements, so from any pair you want to be able to observe these two elements.

```
pair a b = λp. p a b
```

In other words

```
pair = λa.λb.λp. p a b
```

You can then take the first and second projections of a pair easily.

```
fst = λp. p (λx.λy.x)
snd = λp. p (λx.λy.y)
```

You can see

```
fst (pair a b) = (pair a b) (λx.λy.x)
               = (λp. p a b) (λx.λy.x)
               = (λx.λy.x) a b
               = a
```

Case analysis on lists is like pattern matching, in ocaml you would write

```ml
match l with
| nil -> b
| cons h t -> f h t
```

meaning if `l` is `nil` I want to return `b`, and if it is `cons h t` I want to return `f h t`.

There are no recursive calls here, however, applying `l` will automatically do recursion. In particular, you don't get access to `t` but to the value of the recursive call on `t` instead.
To circumvent this we will return both the original list and the value we want to return, using pairs.

```
caseL = λl.λb.λf. snd (l (pair nil b) (λx.λr. pair (cons x (fst r) (f x (fst r)))
```

such that

```
caseL nil b f = b
caseL (cons x l) b f = f x l
```

as we wanted.

Now we can again write `firstn`. Remember, `firstn n` computes a function on lists remove all but the `n` first elements.

```
firstn = λn. n (λl. nil) (λr.λl. caseL l nil (λh.λt. cons h (r t)))
```

It obeys the following structure

```
n b (λr. f r)
```

corresponding to induction on `n`.
For `0` we return the base case `b` and for `n+1` we get the value of the recursive call `r` to produce our answer `f r`.
In our case, the base case is the function `firstn 0` which means the function taking a list and throwing it all away.
The recursive call corresponds to `firstn n` when defining `firstn (n+1)` and in that case we want to do a case analysis on the list as above, using `firstn n` (that is `r`) on the tail, if the list is not empty.

---

```
firstn 2 = 2 (λl. nil) (λr.λl. caseL l nil (λh.λt. cons h (r t)))
         = (λr.λl. caseL l nil (λh.λt. cons h (r t))) ((λr.λl. caseL l nil (λh.λt. cons h (r t))) (λl. nil))
         = (λr.λl. caseL l nil (λh.λt. cons h (r t))) (λl. caseL l nil (λh.λt. cons h ((λl. nil) t)))
         = (λr.λl. caseL l nil (λh.λt. cons h (r t))) (λl. caseL l nil (λh.λt. cons h nil))
         = λl. caseL l nil (λh.λt. cons h ((λl. caseL l nil (λh.λt. cons h nil)) t))
         = λl. caseL l nil (λh.λt. cons h (caseL t nil (λh.λt. cons h nil)))
```

So if you look hard enough you can already see this a function that will only get the two first elements of a list.

```
firstn 2 (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 nil))))
= caseL (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 nil)))) nil (λh.λt. cons h (caseL t nil (λh.λt. cons h nil)))
= (λh.λt. cons h (caseL t nil (λh.λt. cons h nil))) 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 nil)))
= cons 1 (caseL (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 nil))) nil (λh.λt. cons h nil))
= cons 1 ((λh.λt. cons h nil) 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 nil)))
= cons 1 (cons 2 nil)
```

Comment: 0 true (λm. false) = true, 
what does it mean 'λm. false'?

Comment: `λm. false` is just the constant function returning `false`, I assumed you knew what `false` was given you use it in your question.

Comment: Now it’s clear, all that you gave as an explanation I read in the book, could you show a more complex example, for example, dividing a list into two lists?

Comment: You could write `firstn` and `skipn` taking a natural number `n` and a list `l` to return either the `n` first elements of `l`, or `l` without those `n` elements. In both cases you would recurse on `n` and `l`.

Comment: I added the `firstn` example, but it's a bit more involved I would say. If you had a programming language in which you could test it, it might help you build those more efficiently.

Comment: I don’t understand how to recursively call the “firstn” function with 2 arguments l and n (λr.λl), because initially it takes 1 argument to the input - λn

Comment: "length l = l 0 (λ_.λn. succ n)" I did not understand what 'λ_' means. I understand correctly that the function lenght = λl. l 0 (λl.λn. succ n), where λl.λn. succ n is another function that takes a list l and a counter n.
But how does this whole record work. So I got the list l, am I checking it for 'nill'? and then return '0' if not 'nill' then do (λl.λn. succ n)?

Comment: Could you write a function 'firstn' which takes input 'n' and 'l' and gets a new list of 'n div 2' elements at the output? This will be easier to understand.

Comment: I mean my function `firstn` is generic so if you give it `n div 2` and `l` it will already do that. When I write `λ_.` I mean I write a function ignoring its argument, so I don't bother giving it a name. If you have a list `l` you give it first what you in case `l` is `nil` and then what you do if it is `cons h t`.

Comment: I explained even more, but I can't do it all for you.

Comment: I am grateful for your explanations. But could you write a trace of the function 'firstn=λn. n (λl. nil) (λr.λl. caseL l nil (λh.λt. cons h (r t)))' to the end.
How did you do this for fst (pair a b).
For example firstn 2 (1,2,3,4)

Comment: I added this example at the end.